# C# - Add values from list in a fluent interface

Tags: c#, linq, fluent

I am the following code:

```
var token = new JwtBuilder()
    .WithAlgorithm(new HMACSHA256Algorithm())
    .WithSecret(_Signature)
    .AddClaim("test", 3)
    .Build();
```

I would like to add multiple values (called 'claims' here):

```
    .AddClaim("test", 3)
    .AddClaim("test2", 4)
    .AddClaim("test3", 5)
```

If I have a dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary;
```

how can I write the expression so all the values from the dictionary are added? (pseudo code: AddClaim(myDictionary)).

Edit:
I'm looking for a method that fits the 'fluent' flow and not an external loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you want a method that's in the API you're using, then that's up to the implementors of the API. E.g. maybe you're using [Jwt.Net](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet) here, you'd have to have something like that added if you want that feature "out-of-the-box".

Otherwise, you can't get out of writing the loop yourself. But, what you can do is encapsulate the loop in an extension method:

```
static class JwtExtensions
{
    public static JwtBuilder AddClaims<TKey, TValue>(this JwtBuilder builder, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            builder.AddClaim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Then you can write something like this:

```
var token = new JwtBuilder()
    .WithAlgorithm(new HMACSHA256Algorithm())
    .WithSecret(_Signature)
    .AddClaims(myDictionary)
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you, you are looking to extend the fluent interface of the `JwtBuilder` class

My spidey senses tells me there is no interface being passed around via the other methods like `WithAlgorithm` and most likely just the 'JwtBuilder` class itself

In this case you could easily implement an [`extension method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to acheive your wildest dreams

```
public static class JwtBuilder Extensions
{
    public static JwtBuilder AddClaims(this JwtBuilder source, Dictionary<string, int> claims)
    {
        for (KeyValuePair<string, int> claim in claims) 
        {
            source.AddClaim(claim .Key, claim .Value);
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

> **Note** : you hould check the return type of the other methods as it might be an interface, in that case just use it in your extension me your extension method

Which would look something like this

```
public static IInterface AddClaims(this <IInterface> source, Dictionary<string, int> claims)

// Or  

public static T AddClaims<T>(this T source, Dictionary<string, int> claims)
where T : ISomeInterface
```

Comment: yes, that's what Peter proposed above; it is what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @Thomas sorry for some reason i didnt get that update , i was suitable late to the party

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get around using a loop here:

```
var tokenBuilder = new JwtBuilder()
    .WithAlgorithm(new HMACSHA256Algorithm())
    .WithSecret(_Signature);

for (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in myDictionary) {
    tokenBuilder.AddClaim(entry.Key, entry.Value);
}

var token = tokenBuilder.build();
```

Comment: I should have precised in the original question that I'm looking for a way that's part of the fluent expression and not 'break' the flow with a loop. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop

```
for (KeyValuePair<string, int> claimval in myDictionary) {
    tokenBuilder.AddClaim(claimval.Key, claimval.Value);
}
```

Comment: check comment above